# Scaling of an eigenvalue with the coupling constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, eigenvalue

Consider the Hamiltonian $H = - \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+gx^{2N}$.

Scaling out the coupling constant $g$, the eigenvalues scale as $\lambda \propto g^{\frac{2}{N+2}}$. So, we can drop the g dependence and just consider the numerical value of the eigenvalues and the associated spectral functions at $g=1$.

I understand that if the eigenvalues do scale as $\lambda \propto g^{\frac{2}{N+2}}$, then the eigenvalues remain on the same order of magnitude for increasing values of N (as a power of g). As a result, the value of g makes little difference to the value of the eigenvalues. That, I understand.

What I don't understand though is why the eigenvalues scale as $\lambda \propto g^{\frac{2}{N+2}}$ in the first place. Could somebody pleas explain? :(

Comment: Have you tried to actually *calculate* the eigenvalues of this $H$, i.e. solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation?

Comment: I haven't - no!. I am not even sure if this is a solvable system, though. I could try to solve for the eigenvalues if I knew that would give me clues to my problem. Otherwise, it might just be a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \alpha y$. Express the Hamiltonian in terms of $y$. For what value of $\alpha$ does the coupling constant "factor out"?

Comment: I have expressed the Hamiltonian in terms of $y$. But I am not sure what 'factor out' is supposed to mean.

Comment: Means you can write $H = g^n f\left( \frac{d}{dy}, y\right)$. In other words, you choose $\alpha$ such that both the kinetic and potential terms involve the same powet of $g$